# Updating a Panda dataframe using an apply and where, and a second apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
>>>df  
               name  threshold      ...   time                     
   0            a          no       ...   1.1
   1            a          1        ...   1.5
   2            b          no       ...   1.1
   3            a          2        ...   1.5
   ...
```

For each name (groupby), I'd like to find `df.where['threshold']=='no'` and divide the corresponding value of `time` to the rest of the `name` in the same group (a, b, etc.). I'd like to preserve the rest of the dataframe as it was. I was not able to find an option to do so with df.apply:

```
df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda x: x['threshold'])
```

After which, I can't apply `df.where` on it and I can't quite make this multiple conditions with df.apply.

So the answer should do a `groupby`, `apply` by threshold, `where` threshold is no, `find` corresponding time value and `divide` that to the all of the names in the same group. Note that there is only one `no` per each group name.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: For a given name, are there multiple rows having treshold == "no" or exactly one ?

Comment: There is only one. Sorry for the confusion, updated the question

Comment: Does this include the own time where threshold is no?

Comment: Yes. Each name group has only one threshold with 'no' row and the division should be 1 for that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
df['no_time'] = df['threshold'].eq('no') * df['time']

df['time'] = df['time'] / df.groupby('name')['no_time'].transform('max')

res = df.drop('no_time', axis=1)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
  name threshold      time
0    a        no  1.000000
1    a         1  1.363636
2    b        no  1.000000
3    a         2  1.363636
```

The first step:

```
df['no_time'] = df['threshold'].eq('no') * df['time']
```

creates a new column where the only values different than `0` are where threshold equals *no*.

The second step has two parts, the part 2.1

```
df.groupby('name')['no_time'].transform('max')
```

finds the maximum of the new column (`no_time`) by group i.e. the values of time where the threshold equals *no*. Assuming time is always positive (or at least where threshold equals *no*)

The final part just divide the `df['time']` column by the one from the previous step (2.1)

Comment: Thanks @Dani. Would you be able to elaborate on your answer a bit? What does `.transofr('max')` do here?

Comment: @Amir Updated the answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: Great answer @Dani. I tried to only use df.apply with lambda functions and wasn't able to. perhaps, I should have broken them down into smaller tasks first.